# Sysdate in oracle virtual column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a virtual column in oracle that use a case statement but if I call the SYSDATE function it gave me this error:

```
ORA-54002: only pure functions can be specified in a virtual column expression
```

This is the query:

```
alter table t_requirements ADD
  REQUIREMENT_STATE varchar2(30)
  generated always as(
    CASE
     WHEN t_requirements.activation_date- SYSDATE - 5 <= 0 AND 
       t_requirements.activation_date - SYSDATE > 0 THEN 'Exist'
     WHEN t_requisiti.activation_date - SYSDATE <=0 THEN 'Active'
    END) virtual;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `SYSDATE` to build your virtual column. This is not allowed, because `SYSDATE` is not deterministic, i.e. it doesn't always return the same value. Imagine you build an index on this column. A second later the index would already be invalid!

It seems you should rather be writing a **view** containing this ad hoc computed column.

Comment: What I need is that based on when the query Is executed the value change, is there another solution?

Comment: Yes. Columns don't change when queried. You want a view, i.e. a prepared query, instead. See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504 and the first example.

Comment: Actually I don't know why i havent thought about a View! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`sysdate` is not deterministic. Its value can vary each time we run it. Virtual columns must be deterministic. Otherwise there would be the bizarre situation in which querying a record would changes its value. Quite rightly Oracle doesn't allow that.

This is a scenario where we still have to use a query (perhaps as a view over the table) to display a derived value.

```
select r.*
     , cast(
       CASE
          WHEN r.activation_date- SYSDATE - 5 <= 0 AND 
               r.activation_date - SYSDATE > 0 THEN 'Exist'
          WHEN r.activation_date - SYSDATE <=0 THEN 'Active'
          else 'Inactive'
       END 
       as  varchar2(30)) as REQUIREMENT_STATE
from requirements r
;
```

Incidentally, does your CASE statement need an ELSE? To display something other than a blank when `activation_date` is greater than SYSDATE+5

Comment: What I need is that based on when the query Is executed the value change, is there another solution?

Comment: @Iaconis Simone: This is what we are saying. You want a view, not a virtual column.

Comment: @APC: The `ELSE` branch is for `r.activation_date - SYSDATE > 5`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SYSDATE` to support a virtual column. The virtual column is computed at query time.  If you create a function `ISACTIVE_FROM_TO` such as this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ISACTIVE_FROM_TO (p_active_from IN DATE, p_active_to IN DATE)
    RETURN number
    DETERMINISTIC
IS

BEGIN
    RETURN (CASE WHEN SYSDATE BETWEEN NVL (p_active_from, SYSDATE) AND NVL (p_active_to, SYSDATE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
END;
/
```

And define your virtual column on the table that has the ACTIVE_FROM and ACTIVE_TO date columns:

```
alter table xyz
  add ISACTIVE NUMBER(1) 
   GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ISACTIVE_FROM_TO"(ACTIVE_FROM,ACTIVE_TO));
```

The table will dynamically calculate the value based on `sysdate`.  The function is deterministic ... given the same from/to dates and sysdate it will always return the same value.  The function needs to have the deterministic keyword.

As the sysdate approaches the ACTIVE_TO date/time successive queries of the table will cause the ISACTIVE value to go from 1 to 0 .... since the function calculates the value based on moving SYSDATE.  Operates very much the same as a separate view would.

Comment: This is specifically forbidden in the documentation. In other words, you are relying on undefined behaviour which may fail at any time.